# trying to create table sql in java netbeans

Tags: java

I'am trying to create a database table in java using netbeans following a tutorial but I dont succeed you can find below the code(im begginer in java )
when I ran the code it does complie and there is no errors but when I connect to the the database the table just dont show
 thanx for helping

public class DataBaseDAO {

```
private Properties dbProperties;
private Connection dbConnection;
private String dbURL;
private final String createSalesRecordTableSQL = "create table APP.SALES_RECOREDS("
        + "SN               INTEGER                 NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY" 
        + "INVOICE_NO       VARCHAR(15)                  NOT NULL,"
        + "DESCRIPTION      VARCHAR(150)                 NOT NULL,"
        + "PRICE_SOLD       DOUBLE                       NOT NULL,"
        + "CUSTOMER_NAME    VARCHAR(150)                 NOT NULL"
        + ")";

public DataBaseDAO() {
    try {
        this.dbProperties = this.loadDBProperties();
        String driverName = this.dbProperties.getProperty("derby.driver");
        this.loadDatabaseDriver(driverName);
        if(!this.dbExists()){
            this.createDatabase();
        }
    } catch(IOException xcp) {
        xcp.printStackTrace(System.err);
    } 
}

public final Properties loadDBProperties() throws IOException {
    InputStream dbPropInputStream = DataBaseDAO.class.getResourceAsStream("Configuration.properties");
    this.dbProperties = new Properties();
    this.dbProperties.load(dbPropInputStream);
    return this.dbProperties;
}

public void loadDatabaseDriver(String driverName) {
    try {
        Class.forName(driverName);  
   } catch(ClassNotFoundException xcp) {
       xcp.printStackTrace(System.err);
   }
}

private boolean dbExists() {
    String dbLocation = this.getDatabaseLocation();
    File dbFileDir = new File(dbLocation);
    return dbFileDir.exists(); 
}

public String getDatabaseLocation() {
    String dbLocation = System.getProperty("app.system.database");
    return dbLocation;
}

private boolean createDatabase() {
    boolean bCreated = false;
    this.dbConnection = null;
    this.dbURL = this.getDatabaseURL();
    System.out.println("Database URL: " + this.dbURL);
    this.dbProperties.put("create","true");
    try {
        this.dbConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL, dbProperties);
        bCreated = this.createSalesRecordsTable(this.dbConnection);
    } catch(SQLException xcp) {
        xcp.printStackTrace(System.err);
    }
    this.dbProperties.remove("create");
    return bCreated;
}

public String getDatabaseURL() {
    String derbyURL = this.dbProperties.getProperty("derby.url");
    String databaseDir = System.clearProperty("app.system.database");
    this.dbURL = (derbyURL + databaseDir);
    return this.dbURL;
}

private boolean createSalesRecordsTable(Connection dbConnection) throws SQLException {
    Statement statement = dbConnection.createStatement();
    statement.execute(this.createSalesRecordTableSQL);
    System.out.println("Sales records table was successfully created");
    return true;
}
}
```

Comment: Your create table variable is missing a double quote.  Is that a copying error?

Comment: did you mean this   "NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY" ?

Comment: Can you share the link from youtube? I'll try it and if I succeed, will compare it to your code.

Comment: i dont have problem to share it but it little bit long but if you want https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LyZ449Zz78k&list=PLF4GQnPUdprCBj-ez_FCNNo7jfErUVeKu&index=17

Comment: Maybe also add the contents of your application properties. Ensure that you dont have derby configured to be an in memory database